# How to perform average operation on DataStream in Apache Flink using Java

Tags: java, apache-flink

I am trying to calculate the average for input datastream (no windows) in Flink

I have used a mapper to change the stream from (key, value) to (key, value, 1)

Now I need to sum on both 2nd and 3rd field and divide them by each other.

Input data stream is from socket connection in form of 'KEY VALUE' like 'X 5'

```java
public class AvgViews {

DataStream<Tuple2<String, Double>> AvgViewStream = dataStream
                .map(new AvgViews.RowSplitter())
                .keyBy(0)
                //.??? 



    public static class RowSplitter implements
            MapFunction<String, Tuple3<String, Double, Integer>> {

        public Tuple3<String, Double, Integer> map(String row)
                throws Exception {
            String[] fields = row.split(" ");
            if (fields.length == 2) {
                return new Tuple3<String, Double, Integer>(
                        fields[0],
                        Double.parseDouble(fields[1]),
                        1);
            }
            return null;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a RichMap (or RichFlatMap) that keeps a Tuple2 in keyed state. You'll want to add each incoming record to the state, and emit the average as the output.

The [CountWindowAverage example in the docs](https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-stable/dev/stream/state/state.html#using-managed-keyed-state) does something similar, though a bit more complex.